# How to set the font color for conditional formatting with EPPLUS?

Tags: epplus, conditional-formatting

Does anybody know how to set the font color for conditional formatting with EPPLUS?

```
Using rng = ws.Cells("A7:AD29")
    Dim condSumLn = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(rng)
    condSumLn.Style.Font.Bold = True
    condSumLn.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Drawing.Color.LightGray
    condSumLn.Formula = "If(OFFSET($AD" & iHeadRow + 1 & ",0,0)>0,1,0)"
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution:

```
condSumLn.Style.Font.Color.Color = Drawing.Color.Green
```